# @Autowired attribute that needs a parameter to be instantiated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I'm new to spring boot, and I need to know how to use @autowired in an attribute that needs parameters to be instantiated.
Please bear in mind the following illustrative situation. It would be something like this:

```
public class MyClassA{

public SpecificClass myMethod(){
//some logic
}

}

public class MyClassB extends MyClassA{

@Autowired
MyComponent myComponent (myMethod()); //here is my doubt, because my component needs a parameter to be built

}

@Component
public class MyComponent{
public MyComponent(SpecificClass foo){
this.foo=foo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not really proper design if your intention is to work with dependency injection. There shouldn't be a direct dependency to the superclass' method like that. Injecting the dependencies indirectly as you're supposed to do would result in something like the following

```
public class MyClassB extends MyClassA {
    @Autowired
    private MyComponent myComponent;
}

@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public MyComponent createComponent(SpecificClass foo) {
        // SpecificClass is also injected, providing another layer of indirection
        return new MyComponent(foo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Autowired only tells Spring to inject a component into a constructor, field, or method parameter. The injected component is instantiated by the bean container before that. I assume what you are looking for is a way to create MyComponent in such a way that it also receives a Spring Bean.
In your example you could achieve this with the following

```
@Configuration
public class MyClassA{

    @Bean //the bean would have the name 'myMethod', so maybe change that
    public SpecificClass myMethod(){
        //some logic
    }

}

//this needs to be a component, service, ...
@Component
public class MyClassB {

    @Autowired
    MyComponent myComponent;
}

@Component
public class MyComponent{

    @Autowired //Spring wires the Bean 'myMethod' in here, autowired is not needed in the latest Spring Versions
    public MyComponent(SpecificClass foo){
        this.foo=foo;
    }
}
```

This is a basic Spring question, and not specific to Spring Boot. To better understand wiring you can take a look at the [Spring 4 Framework Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/).